# Ruby on Rails: f.select: how do I remove the label?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

f.select :field, [options]

how do i get it so that it doesn't show the field name next to the box?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Got it... just added

```
:label => ""
```

Comment: where did you add this?